# Export table from Xampp MySQL from file directory

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have an error with Xampp where it will not connect to my database. I have had this error several times in the past and no solutions have helped. I find that uninstalling and reinstalling ends up being the fastest method, however, by doing so I lose my database tables. As I have no access to the default export and import functions, I was wondering how I transfer the tables across.

Last time, I copied and pasted these files into the same directory when I reinstalled Xampp and the tables transferred but the data within did not. The tables had also lost some functionality as well.

[image]
If anyone has any methods to do this I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: have you considered using mysqldump? you can dump your mysql data on a regular basis and if required, you can import from that.

Comment: Have you considered changing the underlying problem rather than treating the symptoms?

Comment: What do you mean that you have no access to the export or import functions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to backup and restore your data is to dump the database to an SQL file. You can use the provided mysqldump tool for that, which is the best tool for the job.

Copying the *entire* MySQL "datadir" (which is probably one level up from the screenshot you've posted) and completely replacing one of your new *stopped* MySQL instance will *probably* work, but is not reliable and is not supported. Since there are other files (such as ibdata1) that handle the overall health and functioning of the entire MySQL instance, you can't only copy over individual database directories. Furthermore, you should only do this when the original and replacement MySQL servers/daemons/services are completely stopped because otherwise there are file corruption or concurrency issues.

Since you're running the server on your own computer, you should grant yourself sufficient access to be able to use mysqldump and use that regularly as a backup, since file-level backups of the data directory are not reliable.