# Transfer MySQL files directory from directory

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, file-transfer

What do I have to do to these files so that I can copy and paste the files into another program using only default windows functions?  Copying and pasting it directly leads to an unstable database and the data within each table does not transfer.

[image]

Comment: Don't do it. The only safe way is to copy the entire xampp\mysql\data directory while the database is stopped. Never play with database file while live, or individually (unless its documented in the OFFICIAL documentation for the version you are using).

Comment: If you need to move your tables files into another location then you must export and import its tablespaces. Read [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Importing InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

As we answered in your other (nearly identical) question [Export table from Xampp MySQL from file directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340787/export-table-from-xampp-mysql-from-file-directory), this is not recommended and can lead to inconsistency. I could repeat here what I said there, but the answer is the same: if the MySQL service is stopped and if the entire datadir is copied and replaced, and if the MySQL versions are similar enough, then you might be able to accomplish this...but it's not supported and not recommended and you're much more likely to lose data than have success. File-level backups are not recommended for MySQL databases, you should export to an SQL file.